# Rspec:: allow every instance to receive a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, mocking

I want to mock a method for every instance of a class. 
if I allow_any_instance_of then it works great if instance_count = 1

However if I have many instances of the same class the second instance isn't caught by the mock.

I'm attempting to get a pile of tokens from different sites.  But during testing I don't really need "real" tokens.  So I plan to mock get_token to return '1111'.

```
class Foo
  def children
     [Bar.new, Bar.new] #....
  end
  def get_tokens
     children.map(&:get_token) || []
  end
end
```

so now how do I not mock out the get_tokens?

Comment: Can you simplify the task by using `x.times.map { double('Bar', get_token: '1111') }` in `children` method?
Otherwise you'll have to use metaprogramming to create `allow_any_instance_of` analogue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about solution like this:

```
require "spec_helper"
require "ostruct"

class Bar
  def get_token
    ("a".."f").to_a.shuffle.join # simulating randomness
  end
end

class Foo
  def children
    [Bar.new, Bar.new, Bar.new]
  end

  def get_tokens
    children.map(&:get_token) || []
  end
end

RSpec.describe Foo do
  before do
    allow(Bar).to receive(:new).and_return(OpenStruct.new(get_token: "123"))
  end

  it "produces proper list of tokens" do
    expect(Foo.new.get_tokens).to eq ["123", "123", "123"]
  end
end
```

We're stubbing `new` method on `Bar` to return *something* that **quacks** with `get_token` (so it behaves like `Bar`), and it returns a fixed string. This is something you can relay on.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks man.. I'd ended up mocking out children instead, but it feels dirty and it feels like I'm testing the mock, not the actual functionality.. still very helpful answer.